# DoG returns empty Mat object with dimensions

Tags: opencv, image-processing, javacv, edge-detection

I am tryin to apply to different gaussian kernels with diffeent sigma

```
Mat gaussianKernel_1 = Imgproc.getGaussianKernel(3, .2, CvType.CV_32F);
Mat gaussianKernel_1 = Imgproc.getGaussianKernel(3, 2.7, CvType.CV_32F);
```

on a gray scaled image, and the get the difference of gaussians DoG by subtracting them. the problem is, after applying the difference of gaussians as shown below
, i got balck image with dimesnsions.

what does it mean, and why i am not getting a mat object contains the difference of gaussian as an image

```
    Mat gaussianKernel_0 = Imgproc.getGaussianKernel(3, .2, CvType.CV_32F);
    if (!gaussianKernel_0.empty()) {
        Mat orignalGrayScaleGaussian = new Mat();
        Imgproc.filter2D(grayScaleMats.getMatAt(0), orignalGrayScaleGaussian, CvType.CV_32F, gaussianKernel_0);
        gauss0GrayScaleMats.newMat(orignalGrayScaleGaussian);
    }

    Mat gaussianKernel_1 = Imgproc.getGaussianKernel(3, 2.7, CvType.CV_32F);
    if (!gaussianKernel_1.empty()) {
        Mat orignalGrayScaleGaussian = new Mat();
        Imgproc.filter2D(grayScaleMats.getMatAt(0), orignalGrayScaleGaussian, CvType.CV_32F, gaussianKernel_1);
        gauss1GrayScaleMats.newMat(orignalGrayScaleGaussian);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Mat pyrDownDest = new Mat();

        if (i == 0) {

            Imgproc.pyrDown(MatFactory.lastAddedObj(gauss0GrayScaleMats.getMatList()), pyrDownDest);
            downSampledMats0.newMat(pyrDownDest);
            MatFactory.writeMat(FilePathUtils.newOutputPath("downSampledMat0_" + i), MatFactory.lastAddedObj(downSampledMats0.getMatList()));

        } else {

            Imgproc.pyrDown(MatFactory.lastAddedObj(downSampledMats0.getMatList()), pyrDownDest);
            downSampledMats0.newMat(pyrDownDest);
            MatFactory.writeMat(FilePathUtils.newOutputPath("downSampledMat0_" + i), MatFactory.lastAddedObj(downSampledMats0.getMatList()));
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        Mat pyrDownDest = new Mat();

        if (i == 0) {

            Imgproc.pyrDown(MatFactory.lastAddedObj(gauss1GrayScaleMats.getMatList()), pyrDownDest);
            downSampledMats1.newMat(pyrDownDest);
            MatFactory.writeMat(FilePathUtils.newOutputPath("downSampledMat1_" + i), MatFactory.lastAddedObj(downSampledMats1.getMatList()));

        } else {

            Imgproc.pyrDown(MatFactory.lastAddedObj(downSampledMats1.getMatList()), pyrDownDest);
            downSampledMats1.newMat(pyrDownDest);
            MatFactory.writeMat(FilePathUtils.newOutputPath("downSampledMat1_" + i), MatFactory.lastAddedObj(downSampledMats1.getMatList()));
        }
    }

    Log.D(TAG, "MainClass", "downSampledMats0Size: " + downSampledMats0.getMatList().size());
    Log.D(TAG, "MainClass", "downSampledMats1Size: " + downSampledMats1.getMatList().size());

    Mat desResize0 = new Mat();
    Mat desResize1 = new Mat();
    Imgproc.resize(downSampledMats0.getMatAt(3), desResize0, downSampledMats0.getMatAt(2).size());
    Imgproc.resize(downSampledMats1.getMatAt(3), desResize1, downSampledMats1.getMatAt(2).size());


    Mat DoG = new Mat();
    Core.subtract(desResize0, desResize1, DoG);
    if (!DoG.empty()){
        MatFactory.writeMat(FilePathUtils.newOutputPath("DoG"), DoG);
    } else {
        Log.W(TAG, "MainClass", "DoG mat is empty");
    }
}
```